# Which of the following options is true?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two $3x3$, such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$. Then $(A+B)^2$ is:

(A) $A^2+B^2+2AB$

(B) $A^2+B^2$

(C)$A+B$

(D)$2A+2B$

It is obvious that option B and option C are wrong, because it would not be satisfied if we take $A=B=I$. But, you cannot generalise them both to be identity. Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2\;\;\color{red}{(**)}$$

but we also have that

$$\begin{cases}&B=AB\implies B^2=ABAB=A(BA)B=AAB=AB\\{}\\&A=BA\implies A^2=BABA=B(AB)A=BBA=BA\end{cases}$$

so finally

$$\color{red}{(**)}\implies (A+B)^2=BA+AB+BA+AB=2AB+2BA=2B+2A$$